# Digital magazines on google play/android Market: does it work like Apple newsstand?

Tags: google-play-store

I apologize if I may seem a bit confused but actually I need some direction to make up my mind about digital magazines publication on google play /android markets.

I'm comparing to the Apple store/ Apple newsstand just because I already know the general work flow on iOS devices.

I'm from Italy and I see the google play magazines has been enabled lately in for my country. Last week it wasn't  available.

So questions are:
If i have a Android device where am I supposed to search for digital publications?
(I ask the above since I can't find the same famous publications I find on Apple Store)
Is there a counterpart of newsstand?

Answer (score 2):

I've never used the Apple Store, so I can't help you with comparing them, but to answer the parts that I can.

On a PC you can look through the website for the [Magazines section of the Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/magazines) to find magazines. You should be able to find areas for [Top Magazines](https://play.google.com/store/magazines/collection/topselling_paid), [Staff Favourites](https://play.google.com/store/magazines/collection/featured) and various other Categories.

On your phone or tablet you can use the [Google Play Magazines app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.magazines) or the Play Store app. Either open the Magazines app and press the overflow button at the top left and select Shop, or open the Play Store app and select the Magazines category from the top of the first screen.

If Magazines have only just become available in your country then it is very likely that Google haven't set up deals with all of the magazine publishers in your country yet, so there may be a smaller selection of magazines than you're expecting. I know that when Magazines became available in the UK it seemed to take about 3 months before some of my favourite magazines started showing up.